# How to integrate paypal in context express checkout

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, paypal, express-checkout

I want to integrate PayPal express checkout as pop up on my website rather than redirecting to PayPal, I have to make payment using jquery ajax is there any tutorial or link, for example, it would help for me thanks.

Comment: I don't believe PayPal works like this, due to security reasons, just as many other payment systems

Answer (score 0):

Rahul,

Express Checkout: It gives your buyers a simplified checkout experience that keeps them local to your website or mobile app throughout the payment authorization process and lets them use their PayPal balance, bank account, or credit card to pay without sharing or entering any sensitive information on your site.

To know more, [click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/)

[Click here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/) for the sample code & interactive demo

To use the PayPal EC, you'll need the PayPal REST API credentials. [Click here](https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/how-do-i-create-rest-api-credentials-ts1949) to generate it from the PayPal developer portal.

Comment: Hi, @NIRAJ i followed above link suggested by you and run on localhost but i facing an issue that after an successful payment it doesn't  show either credit amount on business facilitator account as well debit on buyer account, have you any idea please suggest

Comment: Hi @Rahul, normally It should show on the transaction history page. Contact the PayPal MTS for better assistance: https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/